# How to get an Amazon ECR container URI for a specific model image in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I want to know if it's possible to get an Amazon ECR container URI for a specific image programmatically (using AWS CLI or Python). For example, if I need the URL for the latest `linear-learner` (built-in model) image for the `eu-central-1` region.

Expected result:

```
664544806723.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/linear-learner:latest
```

EDIT: I have found the solution with `get_image_uri`. It looks like this function will be depreceated and I don't know how to use `ImageURIProvider` instead.

Comment: You can construct the URL by parsing the output of `aws ecr describe-images --repository-name <repository-name>` using `jq`.

Comment: @HediBejaoui In this case I need to know the repository name (need to google). Could you show an example, please?

Comment: My apologies, I missed the fact that `linear-learner` was a built-in model and not hosted in your ECR repository. Kindly ignore my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer versions of SageMaker SDK have a more centralized API for getting the URIs:

```py
import sagemaker 
sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("linear-learner", "eu-central-1")
```

which gives the expected result:

```
664544806723.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/linear-learner:1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the function `get_image_uri`:

```
from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri

region = boto3.Session().region_name
#or region = 'eu-central-1'

get_image_uri(region_name=region,
              repo_name='linear-learner',
              repo_version='latest')
```

Output:

```
664544806723.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/linear-learner:latest
```

Warning:

```
'get_image_uri' method will be deprecated in favor of 'ImageURIProvider' class in SageMaker Python SDK v2.
```

It looks like this function will be deprecated and I can't find how to use `ImageURIProvider` instead.

Answer (score -1):

from sagemaker import image_uris
container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("linear-learner", boto3.Session().region_name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).